# Generating only backend in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am building an Sails.js app which would potentially have a single frontend worker and lots of backend workers.

These *backend workers* would not answer requests - they would process data for themselves, and store it for consumption by the frontend.

Is it possible to `sails new` an app without all the frontend scaffolding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the command `--no-frontend`, for example:

```
sails new project --no-frontend
```

This will generate a project without the frontend scaffolding.

Comment: Still get the following error, any idea how to supress it?
info: Could not find module: ejs in path: C:\project_root\node_modules
error: Ignoring attempt to bind route (`/`) to unknown view: `homepage`